# Reading values from arduino over ethernet by PHP getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, arduino

I want to read values from Arduino over ethernet module and display them on my home network and save them. I tried this: I used library ETHER_28J60.h and function ethernet.print. I saw Arduino page,OK. Then I tried to use PHP getElementsByTagName to save the displayed values: it works, but in Arduino there are again and again ethernet.serviceRequest() events (Arduino withstands it from a few hours to a day and then stack). Can I somehow stop sending requests from PHP code, or there is some my mistake elsewhere or it is wrong approach at all? Thanks a lot.

Arduino code:

```
    void loop(void)
...
if (ethernet.serviceRequest()) {  
ethernet.print("<br>Temoerature: <temperature>");
ethernet.print(ANvrch); ethernet.print("</temperature>");
ethernet.respond();
delay(1900); 
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$ff = fopen("./teploty.txt", "a+");     
if(!$ff) die();

$stranka = file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.6');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($stranka);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('temperature');
foreach ($nodes as $node) 
{  
  fputs($ff, $node->nodeValue.";");
} 
fputs($ff, "\r\n");
fclose($ff);
?>
```